# ¿Cómo validar opción de select no se repita en textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tengo un elemento `html` `select` o `combobox` del cual cuando seleccionan una opción se inserta en un `textarea` ¿Cómo puedo validar que no se inserte en el `textarea` una opción repetida?

traté de validar con el código de abajo, pero no lo consegui:

```js
            $("#accesoriosEquipo").change(function () {

                $("#accesoriosEquipo option:first").val();
                              

                if ($('#accesoriosEquipo').val() == $("#accesoriosElegidos").val()) {
                    alert("Opción ya elegida")
                } else {
                    //alert("ok");
                    if ($("#accesoriosElegidos").val() == "") {
                        $('#accesoriosElegidos').val($('#accesoriosEquipo').val());
                    } else {
                        $('#accesoriosElegidos').val($('#accesoriosElegidos').val() + "\n" + $("#accesoriosEquipo").val());
                    }

                }

            });
```

Comment: Podrías añadir tambien el html que usas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mira este ejemplo.

Descompongo el texto del textarea en un array separando los valores por el salto de línea y comprueba si existe el valor con el método indexOf:

```js
$("#accesoriosEquipo").change(function () {
  var valor = $("#accesoriosEquipo").val();
  var texto = $("#accesoriosElegidos").val();
  if (texto.split("\n").indexOf(valor) < 0 ){
    $("#accesoriosElegidos").val(texto + valor + "\n");
  }
  else{
    alert("Opción ya elegida");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="accesoriosEquipo">
  <option value="Opción 1">Opción 1</option>
  <option value="Opción 2">Opción 2</option>
  <option value="Opción 3">Opción 3</option>
  <option value="Opción 4">Opción 4</option>
  <option value="Opción 5">Opción 5</option>
  <option value="Opción 6">Opción 6</option>
</select>
<br />
<textarea id="accesoriosElegidos" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea>
```

Comment: Ok amigo, si es justamente lo que quería hacer gracias! @Asier Villanueva

Answer (score 1):

Solución:

```js
$("#accesoriosEquipo").change(function () {
  var texto = $('#accesoriosEquipo option:selected').text();
$("#accesoriosElegidos").append($('<option>',{value:this.value, text:texto}));
  $('#accesoriosEquipo option:selected').hide();
  $('#accesoriosEquipo option:first').attr('selected','selected');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Accesorios Equipo
<select id="accesoriosEquipo">
  <option>Elegir Uno</option>
<option value="1">Uno</option>
<option value="2">Dos</option>
<option value="3">Tres</option>
</select>
<br/>
Accesorios Elegidos
<select id="accesoriosElegidos">
  <option>Ya Elegidos</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Deberías añadir una explicación a la respuesta (qué hace y cómo soluciona el problema). Sinceramente, no veo cómo este código responde a la pregunta

Comment: Hola Alvaro Montoro, puedes ejecutar el fragmento del código para verificar el funcionamiento. De igual forma puedes leer con detención el mismo script y podras verificar que es otra posible solución... Saludos.

Comment: Yo entiendo y sé lo que hace el script, pero para una persona con menos experiencia que no comprenda el código, esta respuesta es inútil porque no incluye ni un pequeño comentario sobre cómo funciona